# gpgme passphrase protection for signature

Tags: c++, pgp, gpgme

I am trying to dig myself into the gpgme library. My first step for this was to copy/paste the function given in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596856/gnupgme-gpg-signature-c).
I created a fresh key, which is the only one in my gpg installation:

```
> gpg --list-keys
/home/frank/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------------
pub   4096R/XXXXXXXX 2015-07-11
uid                  Frank Xxxxxx <xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xx>
sub   4096R/XXXXXXXX 2015-07-11
```

The key is passphrase protected.

When I sign a test file with `gpg --sign testfile.txt` gpg asks me for the pass phrase, as expected. But when I use the copy/pasted function mentioned above it signs the test file without complaint and without knowing the pass phrase to my private key.

I can verify both signatures with `gpg --verify testfile.txt.gpg` and it tells me in both cases that the signature was good (The time stamp of course differs):

```
gpg: Signature made Wed 15 Jul 2015 07:33:00 PM CEST using RSA key ID XXXXXXXX
gpg: Good signature from "Frank Xxxxxx <xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xx>"
```

Maybe this is a total crypto-noob question but don't you need the passphrase to decrypt the private key in order to sign anything?

Comment: _"... but don't you need the passphrase ..."_ The answer points out you have some automatism installed taking the passphrase from a store connected to your User ID. Also you might check the [GnuPg](https://www.gnupg.org/features.html) reference documentation.

Comment: But the gpg program asks me everytime I use it for the passphrase. If there was some passphrase cache so low-level that the gpgme lib uses it, wouldn't the gpg command also use this?

Comment: Just to be sure, I set the passphrase callback explicitly to NULL:
https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Passphrase-Callback.html#Passphrase-Callback
 but still no passphrase is asked for.

Comment: It seems like the `gpg-agent` is caching the passphrase. Using GnuPG 2 it might be possible you cannot prevent this using GPGME, although I'm not familiar with this API. Try disabling caching in the `gpg-agent` configuration.

Comment: Thank you both, it was indeed gpg-agent. The reason why the command line tool `gpg` did ask for the passphrase is that it uses gpg version 1 whereas gpgme uses gpg version 2.